# What to do if photoshop drawes pixels way off?

Tags: pixel, pixel-art

I love pixel art, and recently I got Photoshop cs6, but when I try to draw pixels then it draws them way off. Is there a way to fix this? 
[image]

Comment: Hi user67788, can you show a screenshot of this happening? What do you mean way off? Are you zoomed in a lot {seeing the grid, us a 1px brush/pencil and it doesn't place the color in the pixel you're pressing in?

Comment: I think I understand your "issue" and I believe it is a simple matter of you have to press the mouse in compliance with the grid. The grid is not going to move to where your mouse is. A pixel is a square and if you are zoomed in far enough then Photoshop will calculate your clicks in terms of which quadrant is most of your mouse occupying. Are you using the pencil tool? If so then you should see a square box instead of your mouse.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I read what you said and that doesn't seem to be the problem. After a lot more testing I figured that the square of the pencil is favoring the pixel  to his right which means that if your square is partially on the pixel to the right than it will draw on it.